# Changing the browser for Bokeh server

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

My Bokeh apllication when I call show() open up in Mozilla. How do I make it show up in Chrome automatically? I am new to Bokeh. I am using Bokeh 0.12 and Python 3.5 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Well sorry for the noise.

One way to do it is, for e.g.:

```
session = push_session(curdoc())
session.show(mylayout, browser='google-chrome')
```

To get a list of valid values to pass to `browser` I did:

```
import webbrowser
print(webbrowser._browsers)
```